# Break border with text css

Tags: html, css

I want to ask the same question that is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664252/break-border-line-in-a-span), but there are no answers. Does anyone have an answer for this question? I want something that looks like this: [image: example]

The problem is that I have a background picture and I need the picture to be visible through the a-element but not the border.

```
<div class="info">
<a href="#">Some text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Background picture? Where?

Comment: How are you creating the border? What does your current css look like?

Comment: A jsfiddle would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element with a `border-bottom`(or top or a background).

Give it some layout and a `width` to `100%`.

Reduce its `width` virtually to 0 with a negative `margin`.

You may set `overflow:hidden` to its container if needed.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bmGvo/)**

---

pseudo element can be replaced by any inline-block element introduced in HTML right after , with same CSS value.

---

CSS used for the HTML you gave us :

```
.info:after {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  border-bottom:1px yellow solid;
  width:100%;/* you can tune it */
  margin-right:-100%;
  vertical-align:middle;/* set in middle aside text or inline-box */
}
.info {
  overflow:hidden;/* optionnal , but needed in most cases */
  background:#333; /* anything, image, gradient, color */
}
```

Comment: I doubt that the OP may want to add some content to the `.info` like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ywvbh/ and you can see that it will break the effect the OP wants. In this case I think only absolute positioning or using `:before` instead can help.

Comment: @KingKing let see what OP says, and what he meant with .info is that a title , is that a container for a single link as part of a navigation , is that <a> link 'read more' being  last-child  ... ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you might want to try this little hack I used, using bootstrap:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
               <a href="#">A text that breaks a line</a>
            </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  background: url(http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/congruent_outline.png) repeat;
}
.row{
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
 .row .col-xs-4:first-child
,.row .col-xs-4:last-child{
  border-top: solid 4px yellow;
}
.row .col-xs-4:nth-child(2){
  top: -14px;
}
.row .col-xs-4 a{
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

**Here's a working JSFiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/flamedenise/7jseg0ck/10/

Hope it helps :)